# Why is recommended to not use $scope.attribute but $scope.model.attribute in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototypal-inheritance

Reading the ng-book, there is a part that suggest that when using the `$scope`, try to wrap the attributes within another attribute, like this:

`$scope.model.attribute` instead of `$scope.attribute`

According to the author this will be helpful if we have nested controllers as if we don't do it this way, if we were to change the value in the child $scope, it wouldn't go up to the parent.

I don't think I understand why is this necessary? What is the difference between `$scope.model.attribute` and `$scope.attribute` in terms of prototypal inheritance?

Comment: If you set `ng-model` on an `ng-options` element and bind it to `selectedItem`, for example, it will be set in the child scope and not in the controller's scope. If you use `model.selectedItem` and define `model` in the controller, it will work as you expect.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see this fiddle I've made to illustrate this issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/X9KYU/4/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <!--{{message}}<input type="text" ng-model="message">-->
    {{obj.message}}<input type="text" ng-model="obj.message">
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
        <!--{{message}}<input type="text" ng-model="message">-->        
        {{obj.message}}<input type="text" ng-model="obj.message">
    </div>
</div>    
</body>
```

Controller:

```
//Switch between commented/uncommented

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    //$scope.message="Hello";
    $scope.obj={message:"Hello"}
}])
.controller('childCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
}]);
```

If you use a "primitive" (`$scope.message`), editing it from the child controller will not change the value in the parent controller.

As you say, it all has to do with Javascript's prototypical inheritance

Comment: I would like to know why is this happening. Where is the difference between doing $scope.attr and $scope.model.attr?

Comment: Well to fully understand it you should read detailed guide on Javascript inheritance (the linked question is pretty good), but in short, when you're using a primitive, it won't update the value in parent scopes.

Comment: So, this is a primitive $scope.attribute, but this $scope.model.attribute would not be a primitive?